# How to run each_index in ruby till second last element?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, each

I am trying to implement a bubble sort in ruby. For iteration, I used each_index for the input array. I get an error at the last index as i+1 indexed element is nil and ruby gives exception for comparing it to Fixnum. Is there a way around it? Can I stop each_index at the 2nd last element somehow?

```
def bubble_sort(array)
    flag = false
    while flag == false
        array.each_index do |i|
            if array[i] > array[i+1]
                array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
                flag = false
            else
                flag = true
            end
        end
    end
    puts array
end

bubble_sort([2,5,3,8,5,6,10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) .

```
def bubble_sort(array)
    flag = false
    while flag == false
        array.each_index.each_cons(2) do |i,j|
          if array[i] > array[j]
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
            flag = false
        else
            flag = true
        end
        #etc
```